# How to return a Vec of structs that have a String type field from a function?

Tags: rust, return-value, move-semantics, return-type

I'm working  on a lexer that has the function `lex` that should move a vector of scanned tokens to a main program that would then generate a parser to parse the tokens, defined as follows:

```rust
/// ### lex
/// Pushes the tokens generated by
/// `scan_token` to `self.tokens`
fn lex(&mut self) -> Vec<Token> {
    while !Self::is_at_eof(self) {
        self.lexeme_start = self.lookahead;
        self.tokens.push(Self::scan_token(self).unwrap());
    }
    self.tokens
        .push(Token::new(TokenType::EOF, String::from(""), self.row));
    self.tokens
}
```

The vector `self.tokens: Vec<Token>` should contain tokens defined as

```
pub struct Token {
    // -- snip of copyable fields --
    lexeme: String, // <-- the issue
    // -- snip of copyable fields --
}
```

However, this will not compile, as the `String` type does not implement the `Copy` trait. How might I return this vector while passing ownership to the function caller (as in move it)?

I know the function isn't public, so it can't be called by anything outside the module, but it will be once I've tested it successfully.

Comment: What do you expect `self.tokens` to contain after returning?

Comment: Also why are you calling methods through the struct? Why `Self::is_at_eof(self)` instead of `self.is_at_eof()`?

Comment: @Masklinn Because I'm a Rust (and just programming in general) noob and I don't know what I'm doing?

Comment: Fair enough. The `Self::method` (uniform function call syntax-ish) is useful for passing the "method" to higher-order functions (if signatures match), but generally you'd straight call the method as `self.<method>`. Aside from being shorter, it will also try and adapt `self` to the proper reference type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, this will not compile, as the String type does not implement the Copy trait. How might I return this vector while passing ownership to the function caller (as in move it)?

You... can't? It doesn't really make sense, why are you both storing the token stream on self and returning it? One or the other would make sense (after all the caller could just get the tokens from the tokenizer if it wanted to). Or if you want the ability to, say, chain calls for some reason you could return a *reference* to the token stream owned by whatever `Self` is.

```
/// Option 0: return a reference to the Vec (could be mutable, so you could push into it)
fn lex0(&mut self) -> &Vec<Token> {
    while !self.is_at_eof() {
        self.lexeme_start = self.lookahead;
        self.scan_token();
    }
    self.tokens.push(Token::new(TokenType::EOF, String::from(""), self.row));
    &self.tokens
}
/// Option 1: return a slice reference (could be mutable, couldn't push into it)
fn lex1(&mut self) -> &[Token] {
    while !self.is_at_eof() {
        self.lexeme_start = self.lookahead;
        self.scan_token();
    }
    self.tokens.push(Token::new(TokenType::EOF, String::from(""), self.row));
    &self.tokens
}
```

Alternatively, take `self` by value in order to consume it, that way you can *move* the tokens out of `self` as you destroy the latter.

```
/// Option 2: consume lexer and return tokens stream
fn lex2(mut self) -> Vec<Token> {
    while !self.is_at_eof() {
        self.lexeme_start = self.lookahead;
        self.scan_token();
    }
    self.tokens.push(Token::new(TokenType::EOF, String::from(""), self.row));
    self.tokens
}
```

Finally you could implement `Clone` on `Token` and clone the entire Vec to return it, but that seems inefficient.

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Token {...}

/// Option 3: copy tokens stream
fn lex3(&mut self) -> Vec<Token> {
    while !self.is_at_eof() {
        self.lexeme_start = self.lookahead;
        self.scan_token();
    }
    self.tokens.push(Token::new(TokenType::EOF, String::from(""), self.row));
    self.tokens.clone()
}
```

Not really knowing what the underlying need is, it's hard to provide good recommendations.

Comment: I want to be able to pass the sequence (vector) of tokens generated by the lexer to a parser, and then get rid of the lexer. In this case consuming the lexer is indeed of no issue.

Comment: Added a few examples. In this case the `lex2` version would work: have the function just take its self by value (rather than reference), and return `self.tokens` as you're doing now, it'll move the vector out of the lexer and "burn" said lexer.